# Handle all event types in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In an application using jQuery, I'd like to log to the console every time any type of event is triggered, including custom events.

Is there anyway of doing this without modifying the jQuery source, and without binding to a big long list of every possible event type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var oldTrigger = jQuery.event.trigger;

jQuery.event.trigger = function(event, data, elem) {
    // do stuff
    oldTrigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Just need to throughly double check that every trigger does go through this method.

```
trigger: function( type, data ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                    jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, this );
            });
    },
```

At the very least `$.fn.trigger` goes through jQuery.event.trigger

```
            // Trigger the event, it is assumed that "handle" is a function
            var handle = jQuery.data( elem, "handle" );
            if ( handle ) {
                    handle.apply( elem, data );
            }
```

Alternatively you can overwrite `jQuery.data` and intercept the setting of event handlers.

```
for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                            jQuery.event.add( this[i], type, handler, data );
                    }
```

The `bind` method uses `jQuery.event.add` to add handlers. You can also intercept that.

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
        "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
        "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

        // Handle event binding
        jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( fn ) {
                return fn ? this.bind( name, fn ) : this.trigger( name );
        };

        if ( jQuery.attrFn ) {
                jQuery.attrFn[ name ] = true;
        }
});
```

All the standard events go through `$.fn.trigger` or `$.fn.bind`

```
if ( name === "live" ) {
                                // bind live handler
                                context.each(function(){
                                        jQuery.event.add( this, liveConvert( type, selector ),
                                                { data: data, selector: selector, handler: fn, origType: type, origHandler: fn, preType: preType } );
                                });
```

`$.fn.live` goes through `jQuery.event.add`.

In conclusion everything goes through `jQuery.event.add` and that in turns does this :

```
 if ( !eventHandle ) {
                    elemData.handle = eventHandle = function() {
                            // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
                            // an event is called after a page has unloaded
                            return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
                                    jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                                    undefined;
                    };
            }
```

Which is writing the event handler to `jQuery.data( elem )` where `elem` is a DOM Node.

[[**In conclusion**]]

Personally I would say `jQuery.data` is complex and a pain to overwrite safely so instead just overwrite `jQuery.event.add`.

[[**Live Example**]]

http://jsfiddle.net/qLRuT/8/

Comment: Nice approach but you had to modify the jQuery code by overriding it. Vote up nonetheless ;)

Comment: Seems like everything goes through that method except the standard browser events, but that's good enough for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: @Nikhil - I'm fine with patching the method at run-time. I just didn't want to touch the source. :)

Comment: @Nikhil @AndyHume You may also want to consider using `jQuery.sub()` so you only locally overwrite jQuery core methods.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this is logging the `ready` event but not logging the `click` event?  http://jsfiddle.net/qLRuT/1/

Comment: @mVChr try interception `jQuery.event.add` like so : http://jsfiddle.net/qLRuT/8/ Your click handler doesnt trigger it. All your doing is binding which goes through `event.add` and then to `elem.attachEvent / elem.addEventListener`

Comment: @Raynos: I know what you mean. I was just pissed I didn't think of it earlier :P