# Is there a plugin to check which events are called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, plugins, event-handling

I have a script made by third part, and I'd like to know, in some moments, which events are called (change? click? blur?) and from which element.

Is there some plugins for this? (Firefox, Chrome, or every things)

Comment: This post might be a great help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435207/handle-all-event-types-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

This is what you could do with Chrome's developer tools:

[image]